# Norm of the covariant derivative of the Einstein tensor

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, ricci-flow

In their book *Ricci flow: an introduction*, Ben Chow and Dan Knopf give an estimate for $\nabla Ric - \frac{1}{3}\nabla Rg$ on dimension 3 on Lemma 6.40. At a certain point of the proof, they introduce a 3 tensor $X_{ijk}= \nabla_i R_{jk} -\frac{1}{3}\nabla_i R g_{jk}$ and say that

$$|X|^2= |\nabla Ric|^2 - \frac{1}{3}|\nabla R|^2.$$

I haven’t been able to show this last equality and would appreciate any help towards it. I believe the contracted second Bianchi identity will play a role here but don’t know how to use it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing $|X|^2$ directly one has
\begin{align*}
|X|^2&=\nabla_iR_{jk}\nabla^iR^{jk}+\frac{1}{9}\nabla_iRg_{jk}\nabla^iRg^{jk}-\frac{2}{3}\nabla_iR_{jk}\nabla^iRg^{jk}\\
&=|\nabla\operatorname{Ric}|^2+\frac{1}{3}|\nabla R|^2-\frac{2}{3}|\nabla R|^2\\
&=|\nabla\operatorname{Ric}|^2-\frac{1}{3}|\nabla R|^2
\end{align*}